# How Throughput and Response time are related

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, throughput, response-time

I ran a JMeter test for 193 samples
where I could see my average response time as 5915ms and Throghput as 1.19832.

I just want to know how are they exactly related

Comment: error% was 25.389%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

No, but yes.

Both aren't related directly, but when increasing Throughput, it will probably affect server response time due to load/stress on server.

If there are timeout errors response time will probably increase.

But for validation or firewall errors - response time will  probably decrease.

There's a long explanation in [JMeter archive](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/How-are-throughput-and-response-time-related-td4433821.html), last is using Disney to demonstrate:

> Think of your last trip to disney or your favorite amusement park. Lets define capacity of the ride to be the number of people that can sit on the ride per turn (think roller coaster). Throughput will be the number of people that exit the ride per unit of time. Lets define service time the the amount of time you get to sit on the ride. Lets define response time or latency to be your time queuing for the ride (dead time) plus service time.

Answer (score 5):

All the answers are in [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Elapsed time.** JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received.
>
> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

The relationship is: higher response time - lower throughput and vice versa.

You can use charts like [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) for throughput and [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) for response times to get them plotted on your test timeline and [Composite Graph](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/CompositeGraph/) to put them together. This way you will be able to track the trends.

All 3 charts can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of load/Performance testing. Throughput and Response times are inversely proportional. i.e
With increase in response time throughput should decrease.
With increase in Throughput response time should decrease.

You can get more detailed definitions in this blog:

https://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/09/17/measuring-performance-response-vs-latency-vs-throughput-vs-load-vs-scalability-vs-stress-vs-robustness/

Answer (score 0):

Throughout increases to some extent and remains stable when all the resources becomes busy. Now, if user requests increases further at this point response time would increase. But if response time increase is only because of internal queuing then due to the fact that system is taking more requests in at the same time response time is also increasing, throughout doesn't change. When queues are full more requests should fail. If response increase is due to some delay in processing or serving the request, for example running a query on database then due to the fact that system is not accepting more request and at the same time response time is also increasing, consequently throughout would drop. 
Just a general explaination.

Answer (score -5):

Respose Time : It is the time calculated when user send the request till request gets finnished.

Throughput : It is server property that number of transaction or request can be made during certain amount of time. here 1.19832 /minute means server cand hadle 1.19832 sample per minute.

As Respose Time increses Throughput increases.