# Throughput is constant for all the API even though the response time varies significantly over a set duration

Tags: performance, jmeter

I executed a load test for 1 hour in Jmeter. Below is the result

**Request A1** : Samples-130983 Average-488 ms Throughput-34.11

**Request B1** : Samples-130948 Average-170 ms Throughput-34.10

**Request C1** : Samples-130940 Average-151 ms Throughput-34.11

**Request D1** : Samples-130860 Average-79.98 ms Throughput-34.09

**Request E1** : Samples-130925 Average-1757 ms Throughput-33.93

The reference link [How Throughput and Response time are related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552745/how-throughput-and-response-time-are-related) says,

In terms of load/Performance testing. Throughput and Response times are inversely proportional. i.e With increase in response time throughput should decrease. With increase in Throughput response time should decrease

But in the result i have obtained the Throughput remains almost same for all the samples despite of them having varied Response time.

How can Throughput be same for varied Response time?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any timers for pacing?  If you have a pacing and enough JMeter threads threads, you can definitely hit the same throughput with varied response time.

Little's Law
http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-performance-testing-application-of-littles-law-to-workload-models/

https://theperformanceengineer.com/2013/09/11/loadrunner-how-to-calculate-transaction-per-second-tps/

Comment: According to Little's law, Number Of Samples = Average Response time * Throughput. By considering my above requests, number of samples are 130983, response time is 448ms and Throughput is 34.11/s. The formula of little's law doesn't hold good for my results.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any variations in the number of threads between the different tests?
If you have more threads, and the system maxes out at 34/s throughput, than the sample run with say 10 threads will have avg response time that is double that from the same run with 5 threads.

Comment: There are no variations in threads used. We are using 125 threads.

Comment: Are there any errors? Technically you can have failures say by timeout where the total successful (throughput) is held steady, but the errors failure timeout varies.

Comment: I don't see any errors pertaining to timeout issues.