# Response time is good/low but Throughput is also shows low - Jmeter results

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In our case, Jmeter report shows response time low/good for GUI web app (less than 2 secs) but throughput shows 10 req/min. Since response time is low was expecting throughput would be high but it shows only 10/min. What could have gone wrong?
Gone through below questions, but unable to get clue for my issue.

[How Throughput and Response time are related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552745/how-throughput-and-response-time-are-related)

- Users: 100
- Avg res: 2.4 secds
- Throughput: 10/min
- Error%: 0

Ran tests in non-gui mode by making all listeners off. The CPU, Memory utilization of Jmeter instance and application servers are good. Not crossing 30% usage.

Comment: I am suspecting that you might be using Timer with incorrect scope. Can you also paste your test plan scenario image.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, It is recorded script using BlazeMeter. "Uniform Random Timer" is been recorded for HTTP requests with different values. We have not manually defined Times.

Comment: Exactly, can you disable all the Timer and run again? This is surely give you more TPS. Meanwhile, can you also paste the whole Test Plan image that you are currently using, so that I can debug more what is happening?

Comment: Once again Thank you, does it mean 'Timer' value contributes to the response time, Throughput and shows in the Jmeter results. I will share the Test Plan, need to edit the file.

Comment: The Timer execution time is not added to the sampler execution time [Response Time] and does not show in JMeter result. It just delays the Request based upon its scope.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of TestPlan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you're having [Pre Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) or [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) which slow down the execution rate somewhere in your script.

The aforementioned test elements execution time is not included into the response time unless you have a [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/JMeter-Transaction-controller-behavior/) configured to add these into total transaction execution time for all its children.

[image]

You can run your script one time in GUI mode via `Run - Start no pauses` menu entry, this should disable the "sleeps"

[image]

If the delays are necessary in order to closer represent the real user you can just add more threads, the throughput should increase by the same factor unless you have a bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you for valuable suggestions. Though not having Post/Pre Processors and Timers, having the same results 'Throughput is low' and 'ResponseTime' is good. To check the bottleneck where can I start? Instance resource utilization is under control (less than 30%). Please suggest.